# WORDPRESS: Is Custom Fields the solution for my portfolio?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Here's a brief explanation of what I'm trying to do:

My homepage will have about 12 thumbnail images with title, short description, maybe web url (arranged 3 x 4 or whatever). I want each of these entries to link to my single.php page which will show more details about each project, with multiple larger image files that will display with captions to the right of the project description.

I'm thinking the best way to approach this would be to use the 'featured image' for the thumbnail display on the homepage which seems to be working now, but I've been trying to figure out Custom Fields to use for my other images (image1, image2, image3). I can't figure it out. I want to be able to enter all the content and images for a new portfolio piece from one screen. Possible?

Is this doable? If so, how? The Custom Fields are confusing me really badly at this point, even after reading tons of articles online about it.

I'd really appreciate some input! I can't seem to crack this and it's getting a bit frustrating. :P

Comment: are you using a theme or building your own?

Comment: attempting to build my own. I've built one theme previously, but it's been a while and looks like I forgot most of what I learned the first time around. :P

Comment: I wouldn't suggest against using Custom Fields, but since the number of thumbnails is static, you could get your site up quickly and looking the way you like by not using Custom Fields right away. I would do it manually for now and then learn Custom Fields if the number of thumbnails becomes dynamic or as you have more time. Others might disagree with me here. I could be wrong.

Comment: hmm. maybe this version of my question makes more sense. (though I think you're right -- custom fields is wayyyy over my head at this point.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891497/wordpress-trying-to-understand-custom-fields

By doing it manually, what do you mean? There actually will only be one thumbnail per projects, with 1-4 larger view images per project. Do you mean entering it in the content field directly for now? or?

Comment: Are there 12 projects total? Or 12 thumbnails per project? If it's 12 per project, and you are going to be adding projects regularly, then ignore me.

Comment: it will average out to about 12 total projects. with 1-4 images per project. i only envision updating the site maybe 3 times a year. i think I'll try to figure out how to add the images to the content box for now. Should work fine for what it needs to be. Though I'd like to enhance it eventually to make it a little more 'fancy'.

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields are per post key-value pairs.  So you could certainly use them for this purpose.  For instance, you could have custom fields named exactly as suggested: image1, image2, etc.  Note that the generic nature of custom fields does make this at least a little awkward, but it is probably still your best option.

Those keywords must be processed somewhere, and it sounds as if your single.php is the place to do it.  Essentially your single.php is a custom post template, so you can extract the custom field data and render it as you wish.  You will need to write PHP code to do this, and be comfortable in reading the WordPress [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference).

The [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function is probably the most relevant one, but see the others on the main reference.

What you want to do isn't difficult, but is hard to do the first time.  That's because you will be learning all sorts of little nuances of WordPress along the way.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for the info! I just became aware of Custom Post Types. Would this be another option for creating something like this?

Comment: You fetch a meta value by calling [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), like this (inside The Loop): `<? $image1 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "image1", true); ?>`. You can also query for posts using the Custom Fields as described in [Function Reference/query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Answer (score 0):

I really understand your situation. In fact i have already done the same plugin before where you have to attach several images in one post and in one custom field. Here is my solution:

```
$images = trim(get_post_meta($post->ID,'images',true)); 
$images_array = explode(',',$images);
foreach($images_array as $i){
   echo '<img src="'.$i.'"/>';
}
```

Let me know if that helps.