# Wordpress: Index.php to Single.php page disconnect

Tags: wordpress

I apologize for my lack of understanding of such a key concept, but it will sink in eventually!

This is the code on my index.php page. I want each portfolio "item" to link to it's appropriate single.php page which will show more info/images.

```
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 12)); 
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php   
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
    $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
?>
    <div class="item">
    <a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(ID); ?>">This is a link</a></p>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></p>
</div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is the code on my single.php page. I think my loop lines are wrong, as it's pulling in the same one entry no matter what item i click on on the homepage, but I don't know what they should be.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 1)); 
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php   
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
    $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
?>
    <div class="left">
    <a href="<?=$website_url?>"> </a>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

</div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any tips for this Wordpress newbie would be greatly appreciated! NOTE: I know basic HTML and CSS, but PHP is a new concept for me.

Comment: I see you are trying to show a single item from a portfolio, right? In that case, you don't need a loop in single.php because you aren't looping through anything. I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to do without a broader context, such as where this code came from and how you are trying to make it different. If you look at the default theme, you'll see how a single post in a loop links to its single.php page. Try to replicate that behavior.

Comment: Yeah you have the loop going in the first section it looks like, but you don't need it for the single.php page. Take out the while loop so that it just reads: <?php the_post(); ?>

Comment: hmm. I changed that line, but now the page won't display. (Parse error: syntax error)
My code for single.php now reads:
     <?php the_post(); ?>
 
 <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
       <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        
 <div class="left">
  <a href="<?=$website_url?>"> </a>
  <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
  <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: Get rid of endwhile :) You no longer have a while loop.

Comment: are you available for wordpress/php tutoring?? :)

Comment: Haha I am doing this behind a firewall with no access to any of the files. I'm close to blind over here. Hope I got you on the right track.

Comment: yes. thanks much. It's working! and better yet, it's making sense to me now. :) Would you be willing to look at my image question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879839/wordpress-is-custom-fields-the-solution-for-my-portfolio

Answer (score 1):

You do still use the loop to load the_post() with the current post, you just don't need to run a custom query.

try:

```
<?php global $wp_query; ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php   
                    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                    $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
                    $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
                ?>
                    <div class="left">
                    <a href="<?=$website_url?>"> </a>
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```